# Complient link URL does not call onPageFinished in WebView KitKat 4.4.4

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, webview

I have an app that works correctly on all Api's>11 including Kitkat 4.4.2.

However, in KitKat 4.4.4 the onPageFinished() is not firing for 1 link :

> href="http://app.host.com/projects/30/edit/"

.

I know about the KitKat WebView issue, and from what I know this URL should work.

The web app that corresponds to this URL is written in RoR and has [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/301) disabled.

My WebView client is shown below.

I have spent days in trying to get this to work.

If anybody sees anything that is wrong, please let me know.

```
// Set WebView client
        mWebAppView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                Log.d(TAG, "#shouldOverrideUrlLoading url called: " + url);

                // Open an email client on device when openning a mailto: link
                if (MailTo.isMailTo(url)) {
                    Intent intent = null;
                    try {
                        intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                    // open the help link in a browser.
                } else if (url
                        .contains("www.host.com/expertise/business-development/index.cfm")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "should open browser");
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

            }

            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
//              super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                view.clearCache(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "#onPageFinished loaded page is :"+url);
                if (pd.isShowing() && pd != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Inside #onPageFinished, pd dismissed");
                }

                // Change orientation for the table screen for phones so that
                // the tables show correctly
                if ((url.contains("projects"))
                        && ((url.contains("stepfirst"))
                                || (url.contains("stepsecond")) || (url
                                    .contains("edit"))) && !isTablet) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                } else if (!isTablet) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside #onLoadResource url :"+url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside #onPageStarted url :"+url);
            }

            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                    String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside #shouldInterceptRequest url :"+url);
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);

            }



        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is an ugly hack that I decided to use:

While onPageFinished(), onPageStart() and shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not always called by URL's, even if they are correctly formatted.

I found that shouldInterceptRequest() is fired by all incomparable url's I have tried (only limited and not fully scientific) and it gives me the same data for controlling the flow by url, although in an earlier stage in the page load.

So, I used shouldInterceptRequest() instead of the VERY restricted onPageFinished(), onPageStart() and shouldOverrideUrlLoading().

here is the code :

```
// Set WebView client
    mWebAppView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.d(TAG, "#shouldOverrideUrlLoading url called: " + url);

            // Open an email client on device when openning a mailto: link
            if (MailTo.isMailTo(url)) {
                Intent intent = null;
                try {
                    intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
                // open the help link in a browser.
            } else if (url
                    .contains("www.host.com/expertise/business-development/index.cfm")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "should open browser");
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.clearCache(true);
            Log.d(TAG, "#onPageFinished loaded page is :" + url);
            if (pd.isShowing() && pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside #onPageFinished, pd dismissed");
            }

            // Change orientation for the table screen for phones so that
            // the tables show correctly

            if ((url.endsWith("stepfirst/") || url.endsWith("stepsecond/"))&& !isTablet) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (!isTablet && !url.endsWith("edit/")){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside #shouldInterceptRequest url :" + url);

            //This is a hack as the "edit" url isn't firing the onPageFinished.
             if (url.contains("projects") && url.contains("edit")) {
                 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
             }else if(url.contains("users") || url.endsWith("help/") || url.endsWith("projects/")){
                 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


             }
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Yes it's a hack, yes it's limited.... but Android forced my hand.

Hope it helps .